# Remove HTML from string

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am trying to clear the HTML coding from my RSS feed. I can not work out how to set the below to take out the HTML encoding.

```
var rssFeed = XElement.Parse(e.Result);

var currentFeed = this.DataContext as app.ViewModels.FeedViewModel;
var items = from item in rssFeed.Descendants("item")                            
            select new ATP_Tennis_App.ViewModels.FeedItemViewModel()
            {

                Title = item.Element("title").Value,
                DatePublished = DateTime.Parse(item.Element("pubDate").Value),
                Url = item.Element("link").Value,
                Description = item.Element("description").Value
            };

foreach (var item in items)
    currentFeed.Items.Add(item);
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `HtmlAgilityPack` lib? check out http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/discussions/225113

Comment: Does OuterText or OuterHtml have what you need?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just use the following code:

```
var withHtml = "<p>hello <b>there</b></p>";
var withoutHtml = Regex.Replace(withHtml, "<.+?>", string.Empty);
```

This will clean the html leaving only the text, so "hello there"

So, you can just copy and use this function:

```
string RemoveHtmlTags(string html) {
    return Regex.Replace(html, "<.+?>", string.Empty);
}
```

Your code will look something like this:

```
var rssFeed = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
var currentFeed = this.DataContext as app.ViewModels.FeedViewModel;
var items = from item in rssFeed.Descendants("item")                            
            select new ATP_Tennis_App.ViewModels.FeedItemViewModel()
            {

                Title = RemoveHtmlTags(item.Element("title").Value),
                DatePublished = DateTime.Parse(item.Element("pubDate").Value),
                Url = item.Element("link").Value,
                Description = RemoveHtml(item.Element("description").Value)
            };
```

Comment: Can you tell me where i can put this into the the code I have above?

Comment: I've updated my reply with a code sample using your original code

Comment: This won't remove HTML entities like `&quot;` and whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code sample, it works fine on my side

```
public static string RemoveHTMLTags(string value)
    {
        string step1 = Regex.Replace(value, "<[^>]*>", " ");
        string step2 = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(step1);
        return step2;
    }
```

I hope, this code helps you.

Answer (score -2):

Use the following class utility:

```
HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(string);
```

Please don't refer this answer no more.

Comment: @MichaelPeberdy: Suppose Description contains hTMNL tags then you can use following code  to remove HTML tags HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Description );

Comment: hTMNL means nothing, and `HttpUtility.HTMLDecode(string)` purpose is to convert HtmlEntities back to characters. You wanted rep points?

Comment: HTMLDecode doesn't remove any tags. That's not what it's for.