# XML parsing : Reading CDATA

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, rss, xml-parsing, cdata

```
<item><title>this is title</title><guid isPermaLink="true">http://www.i.com/video/nokia-lumia-920-deki-pureview_2879.html</guid><link>http://www.i.com/video/nokia-lumia-920-deki-pureview_2879.html</link>
<description><![CDATA[this is the info.]]></description>
<pubDate>Wed, 5 Sep 2012 22:10:00 UT</pubDate>
<media:content type="image/jpg" expression="sample" fileSize="2956" medium="image" url="http://media.chip.com.tr/images/content/video/88/201209060102428081-0.jpg"/>
<enclosure type="image/jpg" url="http://media.chip.com.tr/images/content/video/88/201209060102428081-0.jpg" length="2956"/></item>
```

I want read the CDATA in <"description">

I wrote this

```
        var x = e.Result;// e is downlaoded xml file

        var videos = XElement.Parse(e.Result);

        var fList = (from haber in videos.Descendants("channel").Elements("item")
                     select new Video
                     {
                         title = haber.Element("title").Value,
                         link = haber.Element("link").Value,
                         //description = ???????
                     }).ToList();
```

what should i write to description ? //EDIT   Answer: The same way

but if the description like this?

```
<![CDATA[<p>Zombiler adına ne umduk ne bulduk!</p> <p> </p><p><img style="margin: 5px 0px 5px 5px; border: 1px solid #333333; float: right;" alt="Black_ops" src="http://or.com/images/stories/haber/haberler6/20120918_Castlevania/Black_ops.jpg" height="0" width="0" /><strong>Black Ops 2</strong>'de Zombi modu olabilir haberi çıktığından beri bir ses, bir görüntü beklerken <strong>Call of Duty</strong>'nin resmi <strong>Youtube</strong> sayfasında aşağıdaki video yayınlandı. Açıkçası ne demek istiyorlar anlamak güç. <p><a href="http://or.com/haberler/1-yeni-oyunlar/10624-esi-gorulmemis-call-of-duty-videosu">Devamını oku...</a></p>]]>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to use exactly the same code:

```
description = haber.Element("description").Value
```

Or

```
description = (string) haber.Element("description")
```

LINQ to XML will take care of reading the text for you.

Comment: @user1248643: Not really, as you haven't said what goes wrong if you try what I've said. I would expect that to extract the HTML from the element just fine. If you then want to extract the *text from the HTML* then that's a completely separate question, which has relatively little to do with CDATA.

Answer (score 1):

To read the CDATA block you just use the same methods; you what you want is to clean the HTML from it, then check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967747/remove-html-from-string/9968899#9968899).