# How to use replace with tricky characters in C#?

Tags: c#, string, replace

I am trying to replace within a string

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response success="true">
<output><![CDATA[
```

And

```
]]></output>
</response>
```

with nothing.
The problem I am running into is the characters <> and " characters are interacting within the replace.  Meaning, it's not reading those lines as a full string all together as one but breaking the string when it comes to a <> or ".  Here is what I have but I know this isn't right:

```
String responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
            responseString.Replace(@"<<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?><response success=""true""><output><![CDATA[[", "");
            responseString.Replace(@"]]\></output\></response\>", "");
```

What would be the correct code to get the replace to see these lines as just a string?

Comment: Have you considered XML entities like `&#x5564;`? This could be something else that you need to handle. You may want to [use XML parsing capabilities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490637/xml-parsing-reading-cdata) instead.

Comment: Why don't you use regex? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @user3444160 This post explains why http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/668272

Answer (score 4):

A string will never change. The `Replace` method works as follows:

```
string x = "AAA";
string y = x.Replace("A", "B");
//x == "AAA", y == "BBB"
```

However, the real problem is how you handle the XML response data.

---

You should reconsider your approach of handling incoming XML by string replacement. Just get the `CDATA` content using the standard XML library. It's as easy as this:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
...
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
var responseString = doc.Descendants("output").First().Value;
```

The CDATA will already be removed. [This tutorial](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/10/understanding-c-simple-linq-to.html) will teach more about working with XML documents in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Given your document structure, you could simply say something like this:

```
string response = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>"
                + @"<response success=""true"">"
                + @"  <output><![CDATA["
                + @"The output is some arbitrary text and it may be found here."
                + "]]></output>"
                + "</response>"
                ;
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument() ;
document.LoadXml( response ) ;

bool success ;
bool.TryParse( document.DocumentElement.GetAttribute("success"), out success)  ;

string content = document.DocumentElement.InnerText ;

Console.WriteLine( "The response indicated {0}." , success ? "success" : "failure" ) ;
Console.WriteLine( "response content: {0}" , content ) ;
```

And see the expected results on the console:

```
The response indicated success.
response content: The output is some arbitrary text and it may be found here.
```

If your XML document is a wee bit more complex, you can easily select the desired node(s) using an XPath query, thus:

```
string content = document.SelectSingleNode( @"/response/output" ).InnerText;
```