# C# Get nodes inside CDATA of an xml file

Tags: c#, xml, cdata

[image: xml]I have an xml file which has a CDATA section, which has again xml data. I would need to get a specific node from the xml within CDATA and create one more node of the same type and save the xml.

The replace and save functionality works for 1 input. but i want the tag to be appended in the same file. I hope i am clear!

Comment: The entire point of CDATA is that the contents are opaque and not treated as part of a structured DOM (other than "here's a chunk of text"). You'll need to extract the text data and re-parse it as a *separate* DOM, using your choice of XML DOM parser.

Comment: Please post code and data as Text, not as pictures.

Comment: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
 <input><![CDATA[ 
        <inputData>
           <SelectObj1>
               (?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?)
              
               [replace_text]

           </SelectObj1>
        <inputData> 
     ]]>
 </input>

Comment: I want it to be depending on the input which would replace some text in SelectObj tag :

    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
 <input>
    <![CDATA[ 
        <inputData>
           <SelectObj1>
               (?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?)
              
               [replace_text_placeholder]

           </SelectObj1>

            <SelectObj2>
               (?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?)
              
               [replace_text_placeholder]

           </SelectObj2>
        <inputData> 
     ]]>
 </input>

Answer (score 1):

Have o look at this thread [XML parsing : Reading CDATA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490637/xml-parsing-reading-cdata) You probably need to read the *CDATA* value, convert, create node and write it back

Comment: I do get the value within the cdata but i want to know if its possible to get the particular node SelectObj1 from the cdata and duplicate the node  and create SelectObj2 and replace the text inside it. :(

Comment: @sina123 it *is*, but to repeat exactly what Pavel correctly said: "You need to read the CDATA value, convert, create node and write it back" (I removed the "probably", because it is more than probable); you can't work with it inside the CDATA directly, because it is *just text* there

Comment: I am unable to create a node from the cdata as it says "multiple root nodes" exception. This is my CDATA :  
<![CDATA[ 
   <ServerLicence>abc</ServerLicence> 
   <inputData>
     <CreationPreferences></CreationPreferences>
     <SelectObj1>
     (?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?)(FILTER 
     CASESENSITIVE="TRUE" DEPTH="-1" RESULTSPERPAGE="-1" 
     COMMAND="QUERY" )
      Replace_Placeholder 
    </SelectObj1> 
   </inputData>
 ]]>